# Image Resource Loaded via JS Gets Automatically Upgraded to HTTPS

Tags: javascript, https, mixed-content

When loading an image from a secure server via JS with the following code:

var preloadImage = new Image();
preloadImage.src = '**http**://some/resource.png';

The request gets automatically upgraded to https.  Presumably it's a well intentioned feature to stop mixed content.  However the server I'm pointing to can only do http.  I've been browsing the methods and properties available on Image to no avail.  I mean ideally yes, the image would be https, but it's just a temp server spun up on AWS so if we can avoid it for now, that'd be much easier.

Does anyone have a workaround to stop JS automatically upgrading the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out a recent update to most browsers has stopped mixed content all together.  Before it used to throw a warning, now it's just not possible.  We got around it with some nginx reverse proxy magic where we passed the IP in the URL like https://normal-domain/preview/IPADDESSS and it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

It is not trigged from the JS code it's up to the server to check if client can support https and force it.

My suggestion would be to have an intermediate server/proxy that will do the request to the remote server using https and communicate with the origin server using http

Comment: By "up to the server", you mean the one serving the images?  Because that's definitely not forcing https, it can't do https, that's the problem.  When I go to the network log it shows "Request URL: **https**://blahblahblah/image.jpg".  So it's the browser changing the request as far as I can tell.